# How to show only Read-Host value from a text file array?

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I have a text file array JobTitle.txt which looks like this:

```
Sales Co-Worker, TSALES, TSALSK 
Business Navigator, BNOM, BNOMD
```

And I wanted to write a code that would read the user's input and present the second and the third value from the same line. Here's what I wrote:

```
$jobtitledb = Get-Content C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Scripts\JobTitle.txt
$jobtitleinput = Read-Host 'Input the job title'
foreach ($data in $jobtitledb) {
    $jobtitleinput, $basic, $extended = $data -split ','
    Write-Host "Basic template is: "$basic
    Write-Host "Extended template is: "$extended
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make it return desired line only. For clarification, when I input *Sales Co-Worker* I want the program to return:

> Basic template is: TSALES
>   Extended template is: TSALSK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need an if statement that checks to make sure your input was the same as the jobtitle its reading in on each line.

```
$jobtitledb = Get-Content C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Scripts\JobTitle.txt
$jobtitleinput = Read-Host 'Input the job title'
foreach($data in $jobtitledb) {
 $jobtitle, $basic, $extended = $data -split ','
  If ($jobtitle -eq $jobtitleinput) {
   Write-host "Basic template is: "$basic
   Write-host "Extended template is: "$extended
  }
}
```

Also I think when you were reading each line you were assigning the jobtitle to the same variable as the user input, so you should change that as well. Above code should work.

Comment: I added an "else" statement,   
`else {
  Write-Host 'Given job title does not exist'
  }
`
But it runs once for each line. How to make it return only 1 line of "Given job title does not exist"?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an annotated script that should fix your problem. It's mostly the same as the original except where I changed it to store the job tile from the record in `$jobtitle` instead of `$jobtitleinput` and added an if statement. Also added a `$jobnotfound` variable and code to print the appropriate message

```
$jobtitledb = Get-Content C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Scripts\JobTitle.txt
$jobtitleinput = Read-Host 'Input the job title'
$jobnotfound = $ftrue
foreach($data in $jobtitledb)
{
    # Store the job title from the record in $jobtitle instead of 
    # overwriting $inputjobtitle
    $jobtitle, $basic, $extended = $data -split ','
    # check the $jobtitle from record against the $jobtitleinput
    if ($jobtitle -match $jobinputtitle)
    {
        Write-host "Basic template is: "$basic
        Write-host "Extended template is: "$extended
        $jobnotfound = $false
        break
    }
}
if ($jobnotfound)
{
    Write-Host "No job matching '$jobinputtitle' was found."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I added an "else" statement, else { Write-Host 'Given job title does
>   not exist' } But it runs once for each line. How to make it return
>   only 1 line of "Given job title does not exist"?

I can't post comments yet, however you should just be able to use [break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-6) within your else statement to exit the foreach loop.

---------- Edit ----------

The following should provide the desired output.

```
$jobtitledb = Get-Content C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Scripts\JobTitle.txt
$jobtitleinput = Read-Host 'Input the job title'
$found = $false
foreach($data in $jobtitledb) 
{
 $jobtitle, $basic, $extended = $data -split ','
  If ($jobtitle -eq $jobtitleinput) {
   Write-host "Basic template is: "$basic
   Write-host "Extended template is: "$extended
   $found = $true
   break
  }
}
if(!$found)
{
    Write-Host "Given job title does not exist"
}
```

Comment: When I put break in my else statement the foreach loop only checks the first line of my array. For example, if I input _Sales Co-Worker_ it would return the right values, but if I input _Business Navigator_ it would return "Given job title does not exist". Can you help me out with that?

Comment: I've updated my answer - having the if/else withing the foreach would mean it's evaluated with iteration for the loop (and thus executed for each non match). Moving this outside the loop should provide the desired result.

The break will stop iterating the foreach loop once a match is found, if there may be multiple matches then you will want to remove the break.